# modifying addMouseListener()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

This is my button Code onclick i want my program to wait for the user to click one JPanel and as the user clicks the JPanel it should print its name on console.

This button code is not showing the output

```
  JPopupMenu popupMenu_1 = new JPopupMenu();

  JMenuItem mntmOneToOne = new JMenuItem("One to One");




 mntmOneToOne.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Ashad\\Desktop\\oneToone.png"));
 popupMenu_1.add(mntmOneToOne);

 OneToOne.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
 {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
      MouseListener Listen= new MouseAdapter()
      {
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
           {
              String name=new String();
              JPanel panel = (JPanel) me.getSource();   

               //   name = panel.getName(); 

               System.out.println(panel.getName());
           }
       };
    }   

 });
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,

Answer (score 2):

> for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short,
>   runnable, compilable,

because works in my SSCCE, and the answer to

> This is my button Code onclick i want my program to wait for the user
>   to click one JPanel and as the user clicks the JPanel it should print
>   its name on console.

issue must be in rest of your code,

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MyGridLayout {

    public MyGridLayout() {
        JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
        bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 2, 2));
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                JPanel b = new JPanel() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(20, 20);
                    }
                };
                b.putClientProperty("column", row);
                b.putClientProperty("row", col);
                b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        JPanel btn = (JPanel) e.getSource();
                        System.out.println("clicked column " + btn.getClientProperty("column")
                                + ", row " + btn.getClientProperty("row"));
                    }
                });
                b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 1));
                bPanel.add(b);
            }
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PutClientProperty Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(bPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyGridLayout myGridLayout = new MyGridLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared a MouseAdapter in your MouseListener mouseClicked method which just sits there and does exactly nothing because nothing is done with it. If you want to add a MouseListener to a panel do the following:

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) arg0.getSource();   
        System.out.println(panel.getName());
    }
});
```